# Spotlight does not seem to work in finding apps

Tags: spotlight

I have a Spotlight to search for the applications.

[image]

However, nothing shows up when I searched the application.

[image]

What might be wrong? I use Yosemite, and I made sure that spotlight works with this command.

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist`

Comment: Maybe the [spotlight index needs to be rebuilt](http://www.macissues.com/2014/12/12/how-to-determine-when-your-spotlight-index-needs-to-be-rebuilt/)?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That seems likely to be the correct solution. Why don't you make it a proper answer instead of just a comment? :)

Comment: @Thecafremo I didn't want to post just a link as an answer, and didn't have time to write more. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent article on MacIssues [suggests rebuilding the spotlight index](http://www.macissues.com/2014/12/12/how-to-determine-when-your-spotlight-index-needs-to-be-rebuilt/) in situations like this.

Briefly, the proposed solution is to go to the Spotlight preference pane (in System preferences) and add your disk drive to the privacy list, then remove it again.

The article also makes oblique reference to certain “Terminal-based approaches”. The obvious candidate is called `mdutil`. You can use the `-E` flag to erase the local metadata store for the named drive(s), or `-i off` followed by `-i on` to turn indexing off, then on. (Disclaimer: I have not tried this. Check the manual page.)